# At what temperatures does the PS4 warn you and turns itself off about overheating?

Tags: ps4

When a PS4 starts overheating, you get the following message:

> The PS4 is too hot.
>
> Turn off the PS4, and wait until the temperature goes down.

And if the temperature keeps going up, is going to turn off automatically.

- At what temperature are you warned about overheating?
- At what temperature does the console shut down automatically?

Comment: Is this about a specific game?

Comment: No, is about the features of the console

Comment: I hope that the close vote for "Off-topic: Modded Minecraft Support" is just a misclick lol

Comment: I often hear noisy coolers in my PS4 Pro, but I rather don't care about it. I am not afraid that something is gonna burn in my console, because I believe that it was designed to be resistant to high temperatures during playing. I also have a notebook which works loudly all the time because 80C on the CPU, so I am accustomed to hot, loud equipment. I have never had a situation that my console shut down suddenly or something simillar.

Comment: @TravelerVihaan It happens most of the time when the cooling system fails due to bad or non existent maintenance.

Comment: Ufff, thanks god that I have never experienced situation like that. Sometimes when I play, the coolers inside PS4 are spinning very fast and it makes big noise, but PS4 works as it should works, so I am ignoring it for now.

Comment: @TravelerVihaan Don't ignore fans running at 100%, it means that the thermals are bad enough that it needs maintenance due to being unable to provide enough cooling.

Comment: I usually don't ignore situations, when my gear works so loud and it is really warm. But I read that PS4 Pro, especially with supersampling turned on, has a tendency to be loud and warm. My PS4 was really loud during play Mafia 3, but now I play Fallout 76 and it is rather silent, even if I play over 12h (in practice I do not play all this time, but I often left my character in-game world for 1h and I am doing another home stuff in this time, but the console still in game, so...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are warned about the temperature at 85-90 degrees Fahrenheit, or around 29.4-32.2 Degrees Celsius.
The console starts shutting down when it reaches temperatures of over 95 degrees Fahrenheit, or around 35 Celsius.

This is to prevent permanent damage to the solder and wiring inside of the PS4 itself. If the thermals are bad and they need fixing, they might cause the ps4 to overheat [-@Lemon]. If your ps4 is frequently overheating, I would recommend maintenance.
My PS4 had overheating issues aswell, but I figured out that it was due to a broken power cable. Please check if that could possibly be the cause of your issues as well. If you have another cable of the same type, please try that instead.

Comment: I know what extreme overheating can cause, is just that I didn't wanted to stick a thermal probe directly to the APU silicon. Oh, and I know how to do maintenance to a PS4.

Comment: 35 Celsius? Are you sure about that? Do you know that human body's average temperature is about 36 to 37 Celsius? Is PS4 that bad?

Comment: @Skye-AT I am fairly certain, or at least Sony says that 100 degrees F is absolute maximum allowed. (37 degrees C)

Comment: Nevermind; I think I found where you're referring, [PS4 Tech Specs](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/ps4/tech-specs/). "Operating Temperature" does not mean how high the device can take. Take a look at [wikipedia:Operating Temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_temperature), `An operating temperature is the allowable temperature range of the local ambient environment`..., it's not hardware's maximum allowed temperature. Normally, most of APU/CPU can take 90 to 100 Celsius (194 to 212 Fahrenheit), so I think this is false answer...

Comment: See also: [PS4 PRO Temperature After 5 Hrs of Gaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Yb6L-WbjE4&t=53), in this video he says that exhaust heat is reached to 126 Fahrenheit (52 Celsius), easily above 100F/37C.